# Tensorflow gpu error: Dst tensor not initialized

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

It is my first time training a model on GPU. I am using tensorflow. I am getting an error: InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run AssignVariableOp: Dst tensor is not initialized. [Op:AssignVariableOp]

I have tried for solutions like reducing batch size, use tf-nightly but to no avail. I am using Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 8 Gb. I am trying to train an image classification model using Keras Application(Xception).

Comment: Try to run your code on colab first to see if you get same error or not. Thanks!

Comment: I'll have to upload a lot of data for that. I tried the code again today, I am getting some other error. I am going to sort it out first. Thanks.

Comment: TRy Latest Tensorflow version. Set CUDA environment path to Tensorflow and Python. Thank you!